# org.xmlpull.v1.xmlpullparserexception expected start_tag http //schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/

Tags: android, ksoap2

It was working fine and don't know suddenly it is showing error. I am sending data to the server using ksoap2. It is working fine on local server. How to solve this error ???

```
final String WebsiteURL = "http://www.mytestbuddy.com";

final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
String METHOD_NAME = "Sign";
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Sign";
final String URL = "" + WebsiteURL + "/Mobile.asmx";
```

Comment: did u seolve it? Im facing similiar problem